# Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Auth\\TokenGuard::attempt() "api" guard

Tags: api, laravel-8, tokens, laravel-sanctum

Estoy usando Laravel Sanctum para generar tokens de autenticación, pero al momento de hacer login, me devuelve un error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Auth\\TokenGuard::attempt()`. Estoy usando el guard **api** ya que solo usare rutas api.

Este es mi metodo `login` dentro de mi `AuthController`

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $attr = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email|',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6'
    ]);


    if (!$token = auth('api')->attempt($attr)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    return $this->success([
        'token' => auth()->user()->createToken('API Token')->plainTextToken
    ]);
}
```

Este es mi `config/auth.php`

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

y esta es mi ruta

```
Route::post('/auth/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
```

Con el guard **web** si me funciona, pero quiero usar solo **api**

Habia leido que el guard **api** como funciona con tokens no puede hacer un `Auth::attempt()`. Pero ¿Entonces como valido las credenciales para generar el token?

Comment: Prueba sustituir el método `attempt` por el método `validate`

Comment: La intente, pero me retorna  "error": "Unauthorized" . Incluso si mando los datos correctos o incorrectos. @BetaM